# Why does feed_dict use less memory in this case?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Why does `feed_dict` use less GPU memory, compared to `.from_tensor_slices`?
I thought in the following line, Tensorflow would load the entirety of the data to GPU before iterating over the data in the the GPU.

```
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: features,
                                              labels_placeholder: labels})
```

From doc (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#reading_input_data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `.from_tensor_slices` stores your whole dataset in the TensorFlow graph itself (in the form of `tf.constant`), whereas feed_dict only passes the values themselves. The difference should be obvious once you split your data into multiple batches and start feeding them to TensorFlow using `feed_dict` batch by batch because only current batch will be copied onto the GPU. Using `.from_tensor_slices` will result in having the whole dataset at once in GPU even though you are training only on a small subset.

If you feed your whole dataset at once and still are observing a noticeable difference, my guess would be that the `tf.constant` op introduces some memory overhead as your data becomes a part of the computation graph itself which results in a larger memory consumption overall.

See documentation 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices

> Note that if tensors contains a NumPy array, and eager execution is not enabled, the values will be embedded in the graph as one or more tf.constant operations. For large datasets (> 1 GB), this can waste memory and run into byte limits of graph serialization.